# Render class conditionally in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to render a class conditionally. If the mapped item is blank, I'd like there to be a class that renders. Otherwise, no changes. I'm sure this very simple but I'm new at this and not sure how to identify the blank item. Is this a problem with scope? This is the code in my component:

```
const TableBody = (props) => {
  let classes = ''
  classes += (props.data.map === '') ? '' : 'collapse'
  return (
    <tbody>
      {props.data.map((item, index) => (
        <tr key={typy(item, 'sys.id').safeString || index}>
          {props.columns.map(column =>
            <td className={classes} role='cell' key={column.label}>{typy(item, column.path).safeObject}</td>)
          }
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
  )
}
```

All of the `<td>` elements are collapsed so the code I'm using above must not be properly detecting a blank value. Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: **All** of your `td`s are output with the same code, which will either have no class or the `collapse` class. If the check is `td`-specific, it should be *inside* the `props.columns.map` callback, not before it.

Comment: It looks like `props.data` is an array?  That being the case, `props.data.map` would be a function (map is a function of array), which is never equal to an empty string.  So `classes` will always be equal to 'collapse'.

Comment: `props.data.map === ''` doesn't make sense since `props.data.map` is a function. (in addition to what @T.J.Crowder says which is correct)

Comment: As pointed by the comments above, you should do `const classes = props.data.length === 0 ? "" : "collapse"` since `props.data` appears to be an `array`

Comment: I'm trying evaluate the item that is in the column array.

Comment: let classes = ''
classes += (props.columns.length === 0) ? '' : 'collapse'
This doesn't change the end result. Everything is still collapsed. Am I not being specific enough?

Answer (score 0):

Per my comment, `props.data` appears to be an array.  You are checking to see if `props.data.map === ''`, which will *always* evaluate to `false`.  You should probably fix that statement, otherwise the class will always be 'collapse'.  Hope that helps!

Comment: It does help. My next question is how do I incorporate that logic to evaluate against the <td> inside of the column.map ?